# Mostrar 2 modal con 2 botones

Tags: php, modal

Buen dia

Tengo el siguiente codigo y tengo 2 botones mediante los cuales mando a llamar 2 modals diferentes con el primero identificado con id=#editChildresn si me muestra el modal sin problemas, pero al presionar el segundo identificado con id=#folioChildresn no me muestra el segundo formulario solo se queda la pantalla sombreada.

A continuacion anexo imagen de como se queda la pantalla y el codigo que estoy utilizando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="embar" id="employee_data">
        <thead>
            <tr align=center>
                <th># Rampa</th>
                <th># Trailer</th>
                <th>Destino</th>
                <th>Material de descarga</th>
                <th>Fecha Programada</th>
                <th>Liberacion</th>
                <th scope="col">Acción</th>   
                <th>Estatus</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            
            <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resu)){
                
                $id=$row['id_emb'];
                ?>
                
                <tr>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['rampa']?></td>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['trailer'] ?></td>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['plant_code'] ?></td>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['type_material'] ?></td>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['prog_date'] ?></td>
                    <td align=center><?= $row['liberado'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" align="center" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editChildresn<?php echo $row['id_emb']; ?>">
                        <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
                        </button>

                        <button type="button" align="center" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#folioChildresn<?php echo $row['id_emb']; ?>">
                        <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    
                    <?php 
                    
                    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
                    $fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
                    $fecha_final = new DateTime($row['prog_date']);
                    $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');
                    
                    // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
                    
                    if ($dias <0) {
                    echo '<td align=center ><font color="#FF0000">' . $dias . ' de atraso</font></td>';
                }
                elseif ($dias ==0){
                    echo '<td align=center ><font color="#FF8C00">En proceso</font></td>';
                }
                if($dias >=1) {
                    echo '<td align=center ><Font color="#3CB371"> En tiempo </FONT></td>';
                }
                
                echo "</tr>"; ?>
                
                <!--Ventana Modal para Actualizar--->
                <?php  include('ModalEditar.php'); ?>

                <!--Ventana Modal para registrar folio de salida--->
                <?php  include('ModalLiber.php'); ?>
                
                <?php} ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<!--ventana para Liberar--->
<div class="modal fade" id="folioChildresn<?= $row['id_emb']?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #563d7c !important;">
        <h6 class="modal-title" style="color: #fff; text-align: center;">
            Folio de liberacion
        </h6>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>


      <form method="POST" action="recib_lib.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_emb" value="<?= $row['id_emb']?>">

            <div class="modal-body" id="cont_modal">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Folio de liberacion:</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="lib" value="<?php echo $row['liberado']; ?>" required='true' autofocus>
                </div><br>

            <div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
            </div>
       </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!---fin ventana Liberar --->
```

Ya probe con poner los botones en `<td>` separados y de igual manera me deja la pantalla sombreada ya intente incluso con un boton de `danger` y de igual manera no hace nada pero si al segundo boton mando a llamar al mismo modal que el primero si lo abre.

Descubri que si borro la linea de codigo  me funciona el modal que no me abre pero si dejo las dos lineas de codigo donde incluyo los modal solo abre el modaleditar.php, pero sigo sin saber por que

Me podrian orientar

Comment: De momento te falta un `</div>` antes del `</form>`. No se si eso te lo arregla o no.  A simple vista tu código deberia funcionar: https://jsfiddle.net/61vchb3s/1/

Comment: No no lo arregla si lo pobre

Comment: Pues en el enlace que te puse funciona bien.  Compara ese código con el tuyo a ver que diferencias hay y deduce donde puede estar el problema.

Comment: Sale deja checo no habia visto el link

Comment: A ti te funciona por que en esta linea de codigo ```<div class="modal fade" id="add<?= $row['id_emb']?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">``` yo en el id tengo el nombre mas aparte que me llame el id_emb para extrar unos datos silo pongo como tu si funciona pero con la consulta no y aparte estoy usando dos botones para abir 2 modal diferentes

Comment: Agrega en tu pregunta el otro modal.  A ver que le ocurre y si está bien cerrado (no sea que también te falten divs u otras cosas y por ello funcione mal).

Comment: Muchas gracias si era eso que me comentas debere revisar mas a fondo mis codigos

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que lo hayas solucionado. Saludos!

Comment: Igual si gustas agregarlo como respuesta para darte la respuesta

Comment: No, no, da igual, gracias.  Falta el contexto (el otro modal estropeado también) para poder responder y además es lo que se considera un fallo tipográfico que no suele repetirse, y este tipo de preguntas que contienen fallos de sintaxis simples suelen terminar cerradas y eliminadas con el tiempo.

Comment: De hecho, si eliminas la pregunta liberarás de trabajo a los revisores :-)

Comment: Entendido gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No problem :-)  Saludos!

Comment: Vaya, esto se está volviendo viral... al final he tenido que responder a una [pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/561470/263200) tan solo para dejar constancia de como actuar ante este problema.