# no puedo tener y abrir 3 modales en view index laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Tengo una vista index, desde la cual tengo 3 botones que deben abrir tres modales distintos, pero solo abre uno solo, si elimino dos y dejo solo uno (cualquiera de los tres botones) si abre y funcionan, pero si los pongo juntos no abren los tres solo uno, alguien sabe a que se debe? llevo días tratando de conocer las causas del error pero no doy, aqui muestro el código:

```
<td>
    <a href="" data-target="#modal-uno-{{$cat->id}}" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-info">UNO</button></a>
    <a href="" data-target="#modal-dos-{{$cat->id}}" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-success">DOS</button></a>
    <a href="" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$cat->id}}" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></a>
</td>

@include('FOLDER1.FOLDER2.uno')
@include('FOLDER1.FOLDER2.dos')
@include('FOLDER1.FOLDER2.modal')
```

paso código del modal

```
<div class="modal fade modal-right" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-dos-{{$cat->id}}">
{{Form::Open(array('action'=>array('CategoryController@uno',$cat->id),'method'=>'uno'))}}
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Editar</h4>
        </div>
        <label for="producto">Camion</label>
        <input type="text" name="porducto" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="{{$producto}}"></input readonly>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Confirme si desea editar </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    {{Form::Close()}}
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has mirado el código HTML generado en esa vista por dentro con el inspector del navegador (pulsa F12 en tu navegador para ello)?  Aparentemente lo que has puesto tiene sentido y debería funcionar bien supongo, pero me gustaría más ver el HTML generado y revisarlo a nivel del HTML.  Así será más facil encontrar el error creo.

Comment: lo edité para mostrar, los modales estan todos iguales salvo el id que varia por cada uno

Comment: en el HTML veo los dos modales e interan en mi ciclo for el tema que tengo es que cuando hago clic en el boton del segundo modal se queda como oscuro, no se muestra el modal pero si lo veo en el html

Comment: No veo que cierres el primer <div> donde tienes el id... ¿lo cierras bien después?

Comment: si esta cerrado, lo había olvidado, pero no es el problema

Comment: Podría haberlo sido, sobretodo cuando has dicho lo de que se te queda oscuro.  Revisa bien ese HTML que dices que hay cuando se muestra oscuro a ver si hay algo sin cerrar (seguramente no en el modal, sino un poco antes).  En [esta pregunta reciente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/561285/263200) el problema era ese justamente.

Comment: De hecho, si te fijas en antes de tu última edición de la pregunta, cerrabas el </form> sin haber cerrado el </div> antes... revísalos todos a ver si aún hay alguno que lo tienes mal.

Comment: Si era el div en el primer modal  no lo estaba cerrando si pudieras colocar la repuesta así te puedo calificar, ya que me fue de utilidad tu ayuda, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que este tipo de problema ha tenido dos preguntas ([aquí la otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/561285/263200)) en las últimas 24 horas, y ambas se han solucionado del mismo modo, voy a incluir esta respuesta.

Cuando, **usando modales de bootstrap**, se intenten lanzar y tan solo aparezca **el fondo oscuro**, pero no el modal en sí, normalmente se debe a una *mala codificación del HTML que tiene el modal*, donde algún elemento carece del cierre correcto dentro del modal.

En ambas preguntas, ha sucedido que no tan solo era un modal, **sino varios consecutivos**, por lo tanto se afectaban mútuamente provocando ese error.

La solución es **comprobar si los modales abren y cierran correctamente todos sus elementos HTML, sobretodo los DIV, para evitar este comportamiento anómalo**.